# avg of count incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the `Brand` and `Type` of all consoles that get repaired less than average, console types that haven't been repaired have to count towards this average, as well.

So I get the brand and type from the
[console table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j9CL.png).

And I join this to the [Items table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9ugg.png)(`artikel` table in this DB).

Then I left join the items to the [Repairs table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zqmt.png),because I also need the console types that haven't been repaired, not sure if this is correct.

So now to get the amount of repairs per console type I did a count on the `repaired_items_id` in the [Repairs table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zqmt.png) (`repareerd_artikel_id` in the picture),and I grouped it by the same column, and then I took the average of that count.

This is my syntax, I also tried different group by combinations but the results are always wrong.

```
select merk,type from console c  join  artikel a on
a.CONSOLE_ID=c.CONSOLE_ID left join  REPARATIE r on
REPAREERD_ARTIKEL_ID=a.ARTIKEL_ID  group by MERK,TYPE

HAVING  (select avg(A.rcount) from  (select
count(repareerd_artikel_id) AS rcount from REPARATIE group by
REPAREERD_ARTIKEL_ID) A) < (select avg(A.rcount) from  (select
count(repareerd_artikel_id) AS rcount from REPARATIE group by
REPAREERD_ARTIKEL_ID) A)
```

And then I also tried starting with a count instead.

```
HAVING  count(repareerd_artikel_id)<  (select avg(A.rcount) from 
(select count(repareerd_artikel_id) AS rcount from REPARATIE group by
REPAREERD_ARTIKEL_ID) A)
```

I have no idea what to do anymore now so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Removed the mysql tag as the images are clearly from SSMS.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Posting images of tables and data is not helpful. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) Providing this data in a consumable format is much better. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In addition to @SeanLange's excellent advice, please provide the results you get from the code you posted, and why you think it's incorrect.  Remember: no-one here is as familiar with your scenario as you are - things that are glaringly obvious to you will not be obvious to us.  See [ask] and [mcve] for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Using your query (and tbh not checking your images, as they are a pain to navigate to from SO) I think you could do something like this, breaking down the problem into three stages:

Work out the number of repairs for each console, including zeroes;

Work out the average number of repairs across all consoles;

List any repairs that are under the average.

```
WITH AllRepairs AS (
    SELECT 
        merk,
        [type],
        ISNULL(COUNT(r.repareerd_artikel_id), 0) AS repairs
    FROM 
        console c  
        INNER JOIN artikel a ON a.CONSOLE_ID = c.CONSOLE_ID 
        LEFT JOIN REPARATIE r ON r.REPAREERD_ARTIKEL_ID = a.ARTIKEL_ID  
    GROUP BY 
        merk,
        [type]),
AverageRepairs AS (
    SELECT
        AVG(repairs) AS average_repairs
    FROM
        AllRepairs)
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    AllRepairs a 
    CROSS JOIN AverageRepairs ar
WHERE
    a.repairs < ar.average_repairs
ORDER BY
    a.repairs;
```

You might want to worry about comparing integers to a decimal?  For example, if your average number of repairs is 2.9 then only anything under 2 would count as below average.  I think that's probably what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The way I am viewing your info it looks like you do not have any repairs for the items in your items table.  So, I added 2 repairs to one item and 1 repair to another.  In my query, I produce an average across all 11 Merk/Types of 1.5.  I then compare this to the number of repairs for each.  The record with 2 repairs get presented in the result.

```
Create Table #console
(
Console_Id Int,
Merk Varchar(25),
Type VarChar(25),
Kleur VarChar(10),
Jaar_Uitgave Int,
Maat VarChar(10)
)
Insert Into #console Values
(1,'Sony 1','PS4 Slim','Wit',2016,'Slim'),
(2,'Microsoft','XBox','Beige',2004,'Port'),
(3,'Microsoft','XBox 360','Zwart',2011,'Pro'),
(4,'Microsoft','XBox One','Wit',2014,'Pro'),
(5,'Microsoft','XBox One X','Wit',2017,'Pro'),
(6,'Nintendo','NES Classic Edition','Wit',2016,'XL'),
(7,'Nintendo','Switch','Wit',2017,'XL'),
(8,'Nintendo','WII','Wit',2011,'Slim'),
(9,'Nintendo','WII Mini','Wit',2015,'XL'),
(10,'Nintendo','WII U','Wit',2013,'Slim'),
(11,'Sony','PS3','Wit',2013,'Port')

Create Table #Items
(
Artikel_ID Int,
BarCode VarChar(20),
Prijs Float,
Prijs_Per_D Float,
Spel_Of_Console VarChar(25),
Spel_ID Int,
Console_Id Int
)
Insert Into #Items Values
(301,'10000008',300.00,11.00,'Console',Null,3),
(302,'10000017',400.00,15.00,'Console',Null,4),
(303,'10000026',270.00,9.00,'Console',Null,9),
(304,'10000035',200.00,5.00,'Console',Null,6),
(305,'10000044',200.00,5.00,'Console',Null,11),
(306,'10000053',300.00,11.00,'Console',Null,12),
(307,'10000023',60.00,2.00,'Spel',15,Null),
(308,'10000242',36.00,2.00,'Spel',16,Null),
(309,'10000278',35.00,2.00,'Spel',21,Null),
(310,'10000107',66.00,4.00,'Spel',36,Null),
(311,'10000215',45.00,3.00,'Spel',40,Null)

Create Table #Repairs
(
Medewerker_Id Int,
Repareerd_Artikel_Id Int,
Schadenummer Int,
Huurovereenkomst_Id Int,
datum_Gereed DateTime,
Kosten Float,
Reparatiestatus VarChar(25)
)
Insert Into #Repairs Values
(1,259,7,12,'2017-08-03 00:00:00',112.00,'GEREED'),
(2,260,9,14,'2016-09-29 00:00:00',84.00,'GEREED'),
(3,288,19,28,'2017-04-09 00:00:00',96.00,'GEREED'),
(4,292,21,30,'2018-01-27 00:00:00',110.00,'GEREED'),
(5,283,16,24,'2015-12-29 00:00:00',103.00,'GEREED'),
(6,245,1,2,'2017-01-31 00:00:00',160.00,'GEREED'),
(7,245,2,3,'2018-01-18 00:00:00',120.00,'GEREED'),
(8,275,11,19,'2016-04-15 00:00:00',75.00,'GEREED'),
(9,276,12,20,'2015-08-25 00:00:00',174.00,'GEREED'),
(10,283,15,23,'2014-06-10 00:00:00',74.00,'GEREED'),
(11,297,21,34,'2014-07-17 00:00:00',96.00,'GEREED')

Insert Into #Repairs Values
(14,305,21,34,'2014-07-25 00:00:00',96.00,'GEREED'),
(12,301,21,34,'2014-07-17 00:00:00',96.00,'GEREED'),
(13,301,21,34,'2014-07-25 00:00:00',96.00,'GEREED')
```

Query

```
;With cte As
(
   select 
      c.Merk, c.Type,
      Count(r.REPAREERD_ARTIKEL_ID) As cnt
   from 
      #console c Left join 
      #Items a on a.CONSOLE_ID=c.CONSOLE_ID left join 
      #Repairs r on r.REPAREERD_ARTIKEL_ID=a.ARTIKEL_ID 
   group by 
      c.merk, c.type
)
Select 
   *, 
   (Select Count(*) As totrecs From cte) As cntRecs ,
   (Select avg(Cast(cte.cnt As Float)) As avgrecs From cte Where cte.cnt > 0) as avgrecs
From 
   cte
Where cte.cnt > (Select avg(Cast(cte.cnt As Float)) As avgrecs From cte Where cte.cnt > 0)
```

Result:

```
Merk        Type        cnt cntRecs avgrecs
Microsoft   XBox 360    2       11  1.5
```